# Is the 0-1 Knapsack problem where value equals weight NP-complete?

Tags: complexity-theory, np-complete, decision-problem, packing

I have a problem which I suspect is NP-complete. It is easy to prove that it is NP. My current train of thought revolves around using a reduction from knapsack but it would result in instances of 0-1-Knapsack with the value of every item being equal to its weight.

Is this still NP-complete? Or am I missing something?

Comment: This is years too late, but anyway: Your wording suggests that you might be trying to reduce in the wrong direction.  You need to reduce *from* knapsack *to* your problem, meaning that you have to allow *arbitrary* Knapsack instances (which may produce instances of *your problem* that have some special structure) -- no part of this procedure would "result in" Knapsack instances with some special structure.  (OTOH, it does make sense to ask whether some special case of Knapsack is still NP-complete, since it might be easier to reduce from.)

Comment: Yes. What I meant was that I reduce from knapsack but specifically from the "0-1-Knapsack with the value of every item being equal to its weight".

So, it was only my wording that was a little off.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, this is called the [subset-sum problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem#Subset-sum_problem) and is NP-Hard.

Comment: Thanks! I just realized that I did that discovery earlier. Unfortunately I also realized that my reduction didn't work at all. Back to the drawing board. :(

Comment: @ZetaTwo: You are welcome :-)